# How can I prevent another computer from changing the ownership of a folder?

Tags: windows, permissions, ownership

I don't see the point in denying full control permissions to a folder if anyone can go in and make themselves the owner of the folder and allow themselves full control.

I tested this by denying full control permissions of a folder on a USB, then I plugged the USB into another computer, and although there's an initial warning that says access is denied to the folder, it only took a minute to go into the properties and take control of the whole folder.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that on your flash drive, but in the operating system of computers which are going to access the flash drive. Please note that NTFS permissions are meant for isolated and managed environments, where all the users does not have escalated privileges. In windows for example, there's a policy under:

```
Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings> Local Policies > User Right Assignment
```

called **Take ownership of files and folders** and **Administrators** group is granted that right by default. If you remove **Administrators**, then no Administrator can take ownership of files and folders on which he/she has no explicit permission. But as you may know it's machine specific and accessing the flash drive from another machine still allows the Administrators to take ownership of the files and folders on which they have no explicit permission, or  have been explicitly denied to access.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to secure a folder on USB disk.
All methods use a password.

1. Zip up the folder using zip or 7-zip with a password.
2. Install on the disk the portable version of
   [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ)
   and create a password-protected file that looks like another disk
   ([Beginner's Tutorial](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Beginner%27s%20Tutorial)).
3. If you’re using Windows Professional or Enterprise,
   you also have access to the built-in Windows encryption :
   [BitLocker](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6229/how-to-use-bitlocker-on-drives-without-tpm/)
   and the
   [Encrypting File System](https://www.howtogeek.com/136058/geek-school-learning-windows-7-resource-access/).